# Using _EXFUN () in C

Tags: c++, c

https://www.gnu.org/software/m68hc11/examples/stdio_8h-source.html

I wonder what does _exfun () mean above link in using C/C++ and what does it do? I have seen a code fragment. Here is:

```
#ifndef _EXFUN
  # define _EXFUN(N,P) N P
#endif
```

What does this code do? If you explain that, i will be so happy. Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question with better formatting.

Comment: I am sorry. I edited now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In C/C++ anything that starts with a # is a precompiler flag. This meaning that before the program is compiled, a program parses the lines that start with # and do what ever operation they are supposed to do. #if, #ifdef, #ifndef only include the code within their if block so long as the condition is met, meaning if the condition is not met, the code in the if is not compiled. #define is used for macro definition and simple text replacement.

It seems that in the code you reference, if the macro is not already defined, the macro will be defined so that the code below the definiton of the macro will be turned into valid C syntax. I suppose this could be useful if somebody wanted to have the stdio functions do something else or be defined a different way. They would achieve that be defining_EXFUN before stdio.h was included.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it and it chains two statements.

```
_EXFUN(printf("Hello, ");, printf("World!\n");)
```

Apparently, this is a hack used so that the same statement will be preprocessed differently depending on how `_EXFUN` is implemented in the header file. It mainly has to do with declarations. But I can not give any example of when it is useful.

Comment: İt chains two statements but why?

Comment: @leurami Apparently, this is a hack used so that the same statement will be preprocessed differently depending on how `_EXFUN` is implemented in the header file. It mainly has to do with declarations. But I can not give any example of when it is useful.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you for your helping.

Comment: @leurami No problem

Answer (score 0):

The macro is used to overcome the definition on the functions mainly in C headers (`.h` files). This ensure the best support for the compilation whatever can be the platform and the version of the compiler (C ANSI compatible or plain C).

Then `int _EXFUN(scanf, (const char *, ...));` resolves as `int scanf(const char *, ...)`.

Comment: What do you mean by 'overcome the definition'? How would `_EXFUN` macro be defined in different circumstances to make code more portable?